# Java Numbers to words (0-999)

Tags: java, arrays, numbers

This is my first post, and i'm currently struggling with creating a program which can transform the input of a number into its respective word. My code so far is written below, i can't seem to get the tens to work properly i.e 21,31,41,51 etc..

```
public class NumberToWords {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.print("Number: ");
        int value = In.nextInt();
        int onesDigit;
        int tensDigit;
        String [] ones = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten",
            "eleven", "tweleve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"};

        String [] tens = {"", "", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"};

        String [] hundreds = {"one hundred", "two hundred", "three hundred", "four hundred", "five hundred", 
            "six hundred", "seven hundred", "eight hundred", "nine hundred" }; 
  while(value != -1)
 {
   if (value < 20)
    {
        String result = ones[value];
        System.out.println("Result " + result);
        value = In.nextInt();
    }
   if (value > 20 && value < 100)
    {
        tensDigit = value%10;
        onesDigit = value/10;
        System.out.print("Result " + ones[onesDigit] + " " + tens[tensDigit]);
        value = In.nextInt();

    }
 }

}    
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Two hints: Reverse order; And experiment with the division and modulo operators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code is incorrect:

> ```
>  tensDigit = value%10;
>  onesDigit = value/10;
> ```

The tens digit should be `value/10` (that is, 4 if value is 41) while the ones digit should be `value%10` (the remainder when the value is divided by ten).

Use this instead:

```
  tensDigit = value/10;
  onesDigit = value%10;
```

Additionally there are other points to note:

- Nothing will get printed if value is equal to 20, since neither if-condition will match.
- Any value that is divisible by ten and is bigger than ten (twenty, thirty, etc) will print something like "twenty zero". Add another if-statement that handles a special case for `value==0` and make the array entry for zero an empty string.
- Switch the order of concatenation in your print statement to `tens[tensDigit] + " " + ones[onesDigit])`